# How can I convert a HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> to a HashMap<String, String[]>?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`.  I am trying to convert it to a `HashMap<String, String[]>`.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> arrayListMap = new HashMap<>();
HashMap<String, String[]> arrayMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : arrayListMap.entrySet()) {
    arrayMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toArray());
}
```

However, for `entry.getValue().toArray()`, my IDE is giving me the error:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.lang.Object[], required 'java.lang.String[]'.
```

I don't know why, because the `arrayListMap` specifies that I will be working with `String`s.

Why is this not working, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of what is stored in entry (keys and values)?

Comment: This sounds like XY problem. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @DmitryZaitsev:  I don't see an XY problem; wanting to convert between a list and an array was such a specific use case that they included support for it in the API.

Comment: @Makoto I see nothing wrong with converting `List` to array. However, converting one map to another seems odd. Especially with generics.

Comment: @Makoto in general, using collections is preferred over using arrays. And you can do more with a list than you can do with arrays. So doing the transformation is probably a bad idea. The code expecting an array in the map should instead be modified to expect a list.

Comment: @JBNizet:  I don't disagree there; collections are far nicer to work with.  But, this might be the case in which a legacy API which can't be modified that needs to work with more modern code.

Comment: I agree. But if the OP explained *why* he wants to do that transformation, we could guide him towards the best strategy. It could be an XY problem.

Comment: @JBNizet I am compiling a large list of data of an unknown size. The list will never change after being compiled. I then wanted to convert it to an array for speed.

Comment: Converting a ArrayList to an array takes more time than not doing it (It's O(n)). And accessing elements of an ArrayList (which is backed by an array), is not significantly slower than accessing the array directly. So I would keep using the List, and only try to optimize if you really have a perfrmance problem and can prove that transforming to an array would solve it.

Comment: Not to mention that you not only transform the lists into arrays, but also the map holding all the lists to another map holding arrays. My guess is that your optimization adds useless code, and makes the performance worse.

Answer (score 6):

`ArrayList` has overloaded the `toArray` method.

The first form, [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray()), will return an `Object[]` back.  This isn't what you want, since you can't convert an `Object[]` into a `String[]`.

The second form, [`toArray(T[] a)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray(T[])) will return an array back that is typed with whatever array you pass into it.

You need to use the second form here so that the array is correctly typed.

```
arrayMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()
                                  .toArray(new String[entry.getValue().size()]));
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81884/discussion-between-sotirios-delimanolis-and-makoto).

Answer (score -1):

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> arrayListMap = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, String[]> arrayMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> entry : arrayListMap.entrySet()) {
            arrayMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toArray(new String[entry.getValue().size()]));
        }
```

entry.getValue().toArray() will return object array "object[]"

But need String[].

So need to use the method entry.getValue().toArray(T[] a) that returns T[] //generic arg type

Comment: A little explanation would go a long way.